# How to select non null columns only?

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I have 100+ columns in a table, where some of them are filled with 0s and some are null.. how do i select only those columns which have non null values, is there a easier way than using ' is not null ' on every column?

Comment: What if you got `colA, colB; 1, NULL; NULL,2`?

Comment: in this case it has valid values and some rows are null.. so i need both columns

Comment: I assume not all 100 columns in one row .. so please show an example of input and expected output..

Comment: "is there a easier way than using ' is not null ' on every column?" No not really

Comment: the data might need to be "flipped" from 100 columns to less columns and more rows making it vastly easier to query